# BeautifullSoup findall JavaScript alternative?

Tags: javascript

What's the js alternative of this python script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

page = requests.get(url).text

soup = bs(page)
items = soup.findAll('li')
```

I've searched DOM Parser documentation but i can't find anything like `findall()`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
fetch(url).then(res => res.text()).then(page => {
  const parser = new DOMParser()
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(page, "text/html")
  const items = doc.querySelectorAll('li')
})
```

You can call all the methods supported by the [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface on the `doc` constant in this code snippet. Here I used the `querySelectorAll` method that returns a `NodeList` containing all `li` elements in the document.

Comment: This works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try Doing this
items = soup.findAll('li', class='ClassNameofthatparticularli' )

I hope this might work for you. If not ask me again.

Comment: OP wants the JavaScript alternative of the given Python code. Therefore, your answer unfortunately does not help at all!

Comment: I need the JS alternative

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).